# Find The Equation Of the hyperbolic mirror of a Telescope That Contains A Parabolic And Hyperbolic Mirror

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm currently taking a pre-calc/trig class and doing my homework regarding parabolas and hyperbolas.

The word problem is this:

A telescope contains both a parabolic mirror and a hyperbolic mirror. They share focus F1, which is 44ft above the vertex of the parabola. The hyperbola's second focus F2 is 6 ft above the parabola's vertex. The vertex of the hyperbolic mirror is 3ft below F1. Find the equation of the hyperbola if the center is at the origin of a coordinate system and the foci are on the y-axis.

From the above I have gathered the transverse axis is vertical. I believe $C^2$ = 44, $A^2$ = 6, but I'm not sure that $B^2$ = 3. I found the second half the equation by adding 6 + 3 = 9, 44 - 9 = 35. 35 * 3 = 105. $\frac{y^2}{256}$ - $\frac{x^2}{105}$ = 1.

I'm having trouble figuring out how they came to the conclusion of  $\frac{y^2}{256}$.

[image]

Comment: The question should be raised on https://physics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I don't agree : it is a mathematical problem that necessitates no physics knowledge (geometrical optics with geometry and no optics in fact).

Comment: A very similar problem (Cassegrain telescope) with an illustration that is lacking in your question : https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/telescope-contains-parabolic-mirror-hyperbolic-mirror-share-focus-f1-43-feet-vertex-parabo-q33478073

Comment: @JeanMarie That illustration is the same one used for the word problem I am working on. it is the same word problem, just has the numbers in it changed.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for your response, I guess I still don't get it. I've tried doing what you suggested but still haven't gotten the answer that was shown in the homework problem. The answer should come out to $\frac{y^2}{256}$ - $\frac{x^2}{105}$ = 1. I've gotten the second part of the answer worked out, but can't seem to understand how they got the denominator to ${y^2}$, 256.

Comment: Having seen the answer of user376343  I understand that I had forgotten to divide $F_1F_2$ by 2 in order to get $c$. My bad...

Comment: I see now that on your side, you had done $44-9$ instead of $44-6$...

Comment: I have taken the liberty to add to your text a figure that I have made in order that further readers understand the problem at hand.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you very much for all your help. I wasn't sure how to add/embed an image into my problem so I appreciate that you did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the picture.
$F_1F_2=38\Rightarrow c=19.$
The major half-axis is $a=16,\;$ hence $b^2=19^2-16^2=105,$
from where the equation $$\frac{y^2}{256}-\frac{x^2}{105}=1.$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I understand now how they came to the answer they did.

Comment: You are welcome @bgongre I am glad I could help.